# Upload images with form registration

Tags: php, database, file, upload

Hi this is my form code:

```
echo "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"\">\n"; 
echo "<td>User Id</td><td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"user_id\"></td>\n"; 
echo "</tr>\n"; 
echo "<tr>\n"; 
echo "<td>Full Name</td><td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"full_name\">    </td>\n"; 
echo "</tr>\n"; 
echo "<tr>\n"; 
echo "<td>Qualification</td><td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"qualification\"></td>\n"; 
echo "</tr>\n"; 
echo "<tr>\n"; 
echo "<td>Locality</td><td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"locality\"></td>\n"; 
echo "</tr>\n"; 
echo "<tr>\n"; 
echo "<td>Description</td><td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"description\"></td>\n"; 
echo "</tr>\n"; 
echo "<tr>\n"; 
echo "<td>Languages Known</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"language\"></td>\n"; 
echo "</tr>\n"; 
echo "<tr>\n"; 
echo "<td>Experience</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"experience\"></td>\n"; 
echo "</tr>\n"; 
echo "<tr>\n"; 
echo "<td>Dress</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"dress_code\"></td>\n"; 
echo "</tr>\n"; 
echo "<tr>\n"; 
echo "<td>Bank Details</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"bank_details\"></td>\n"; 
echo "</tr>\n"; 
echo "<tr>\n"; 
echo "<td>Two Wheelers</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"two_wheeler\"></td>\n"; 
echo "</tr>\n"; 
echo "<tr>\n"; 
echo "<td>Threshold</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"threshold\"></td>\n"; 
echo "</tr>\n"; 
echo "<tr>\n"; 
echo "<td><input name=\"pic1\" type=\"file\"></td><td><input name=\"pic\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Upload Image\"></td>\n"; // Kindly check this line
echo "</tr>\n"; 
echo "<tr>\n"; 
echo "<td>Photo 2</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"pic2\"></td>\n"; 
echo "</tr>\n"; 
echo "<tr>\n"; 
echo "<td>Photo 3</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"pic3\"></td>\n"; 
echo "</tr>\n"; 
echo "<tr>\n"; 
echo "<td>Photo 4</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"pic4\"></td>\n"; 
echo "</tr>\n"; 
echo "<tr>\n"; 
echo "<td>Photo 5</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"pic5\"></td>\n"; 
echo "</tr>\n"; 
echo "<tr>\n"; 
echo "<td>ID Number</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"id_proof\"></td>\n"; 
echo "</tr>\n"; 
echo "<tr>\n"; 
echo "<td>Contact Details</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"contact_details\"></td>\n"; 
echo "</tr>\n"; 
echo "<tr>\n"; 
echo "<td>Date</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"datetime_added\"></td>\n"; 
echo "</tr>\n"; 
echo "<tr>\n"; 
echo "<td><input id=\"button\" type=\"submit\" name=\"btn-signup\" value=\"Sign-Up\"></td>\n"; 
echo "</tr>\n"; 
echo "</form>\n";
```

I have a confusion that how can i upload a image in the database with form.Below is my php file

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
{
$user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_id']);
$full_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['full_name']);
$qualification = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['qualification']);
$locality = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['locality']);
$description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
$language = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['language']);
$experience = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['experience']);
$dress_code = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dress_code']);
$bank_details = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bank_details']);
$two_wheeler = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['two_wheeler']);
$threshold = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['threshold']);
$pic1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pic1']);
$pic2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pic2']);
$pic3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pic3']);
$pic4 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pic4']);
$pic5 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pic5']);
$id_proof = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id_proof']);
$contact_details = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contact_details']);
$datetime_added = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dtetime_added']);

$uname = trim($uname);
$email = trim($email);
$upass = trim($upass);

$target = "upload/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 

 //This gets all the other information from the form 
 $pic1=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 

 //Writes the photo to the server 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
{ 

//Tells you if its all ok 
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been     uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
} 
else { 

//Gives and error if its not 
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
} 


// email exist or not
$query = "SELECT user_id FROM promoter WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$count = mysql_num_rows($result); // if email not found then register

if($count == 0){

    if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO promoter(user_id,full_name,qualification,locality,description,language,experience,dress_code,bank_details,two_wheeler,threshold,pic2,pic3,pic4,pic5,id_proof,contact_details,datetime_added, target)    VALUES('$user_id','$full_name','$qualification','$locality','$description','$language','$experience','$dress_code','$bank_details','$two_wheeler','$threshold','$pic2','$pic3','$pic4','$pic5','$id_proof','$contact_details','$datetime_added','$target')"))
    {
        ?>
        <script>alert('successfully registered ');</script>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script>alert('error while registering you...');</script>
        <?php
    }       
}
else{
        ?>
        <script>alert('Sorry Email ID already taken ...');</script>
        <?php
}

}
```

There i have given five photo option in the form, but i am testing in the first pic1 only . Help me how can i upload the image file with my code. I am confused how to add image or have to add the image path. Kindly correct my code.

Comment: You have to add the image path in database inorder to retrieve it later

Comment: First of all use mysqli_real_escape_string instead mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: And you don't need to store the image in database you store the path of an image in database,

Comment: So how can i store the path of the image in database?

Comment: You can visit this site. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: How do i Display the uploaded image from the database

Answer (score 0):

Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form tag

`echo "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">\n";`

Comment: dude, i was about to answer this! xD

Comment: Change

`$target = "upload/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); `

to

`$dir_url = "upload/"; 
$target1 = $dir_url . basename( $_FILES['pic1']['name']); 

$target2 = $dir_url . basename( $_FILES['pic2']['name']);

$target3 = $dir_url . basename( $_FILES['pic3']['name']);

$target4 = $dir_url . basename( $_FILES['pic4']['name']);`

Then save `$target1`, `$target2`, `$target3`, `$target4` to your db

Comment: In the form what should i do with the upload button remove it or keep it there , because i have a submit button in the last.

Comment: Now it is echoing Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file

Comment: You can remove all the submit buttons beside the file upload tags and leave the last submit button.

Comment: Check the folder location to see if exists and change `echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";` to `echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file." . $FILES["pic1"]["error"];` where `pic1` is the name of the file you're currently uploading.